# Put an end to rollback wars

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vandalism, rollback-wars

If a question receives *n* (say, 5) rollbacks within a hour, raise a moderator flag and lock the post.

Alternatively, if an edit by a new user (say, no edit approving privs) drops the post quality score of a post "too much" (say, by more than 100), it must go through the edit approval process.

Comment: Should intermediate edits count as rollbacks too then? (Maybe nice but probably not *required*, as if rollbacks are done using plain edits, that just means that the threshold will be reached a bit later — assuming most others will still use the "rollback" link.)

Comment: I assume *post quality score* refers to [Heuristics for detecting a bad answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer), right?

Comment: @Arjan correct.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is for the most part completed:

- Two rollbacks from the same user on a single post will generate a "rollback war" auto-flag for moderator attention.
- An edit which causes a post to become "low quality" will bump the post into the Low Quality Posts review queue if the edit is live for more than 15 minutes.

The post, however, does not get automatically locked upon generating the flag.

Comment: Does the two roll-backs need to happen in a certain time-frame? Or if I happen to roll-back two separated edits (not as part of a "war") on the same post it will also automatically raise a flag?

Answer (score 12):

Yes please. See current real-world example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686856/php-paypal-subscription-with-ipn). The revision histories are a mess, and a lot of noise (42 questions with 20-30 revisions) was bumped unnecessarily, because no mod was present to stop it. (Which is to be expected on a weekend, that's not the issue. But some automated system should be in place to prevent this from getting out of hand.)

Comment: That's just one of _many_ examples. I'm sure Popular Demand will be able to come up with more.

Comment: Wow that's insane.

Comment: Already posted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75902/user-wildly-erasing-all-his-posts-continuously-even-after-we-rollback). He's mad.

Comment: But how do we 'automatically lock' at the non-vandalized revision?

Comment: What @Tim said - worst-case, it gets locked in a bad state waiting for a moderator to intervene. Not the end of the world, but... Raising a moderator flag should be the **first** thing you do when encountering a persistent vandal, not hanging around trying to hit some rollback cap.

Comment: "What you are doing is illegal!"

Comment: @Shog just for the record, flagging a mod is what everyone did first  yesterday. There just weren't any around for quite some time. Still, I agree that continuous rollbacks aren't the most productive thing to do.

Comment: @TimPost I proposed to just lock, but one could detect what the "good copy" is by using the post quality metric, or rollbacking to revision 1 :)

Comment: Aw man, it never hit the 100th rollback mark. :(