# Another user updated the code snippet on my answer & it's incorrect/introduced an error. What's my course of action?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, moderators, code

Another user updated the code snippet on my answer & it's incorrect/introduced an error. What's my course of action?

I can't seem to send them a message, so do I have to manually fix their edit? What's to stop them from introducing another error?

Comment: If you disagree with an edit on your post, you can mention the editor in a comment, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020

Comment: Thanks. I already did that but was wondering if there was a more direct approach. I have now rolled back the answer too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just go to the [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16862066/revisions) (by clicking on the 'edited <timestamp>' link below the post, above the editor's user card), scroll down to the previous revision, and click 'rollback'. That will bring the post back to that state.

[image]

[image]

You've already posted a comment notifying the user of this problem, so they are probably aware and might reply ("sorry, I made a mistake" or "no, you're looking at it the wrong way") or not reply if they don't feel the need to.

In some extreme cases, repeated rollbacks by persistent users will lead to so-called [rollback wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75906/295232); those will trigger an automatic flag so the ♦ moderators will have a look at it. This doesn't happen that often, though: most of the times, the users will be able to settle themselves. If one of my edits gets rolled back by the post author, I usually think "OK, if they don't want their post improved, that's their own choice, fine with me". If what I contributed is really important, I'll probably write an answer in those cases.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no `rollback` option available to me on their edit.

Comment: You need the rollback link on the revision you want to roll back *to*, not the revision you actually want to roll back.

Comment: Thanks! Rolled back. Let's see what happens.