# User refusing to remove unnecessary (and possible offensive) text from post

Tags: discussion, support, flags, suggested-edits

I recently came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917982/how-to-update-highslide-content-after-ajaxcall-without-page-refresh/8930512#8930512) that had some possibly offensive text that was serving no purpose and was just "noise", so I went ahead and flagged the post for moderator attention. I'm not sure if the flag was accepted or not, but a couple minutes later I noticed a moderator removed the text from the post.

I went back a couple minutes later and noticed that the user had added the text back in. So I decided to suggest an edit and the post was instead edited by another user with higher rep than I have. [Then again the user changed the post back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8930512/revisions).

Finally, I decided to again suggest another edit (which probably wasn't the best idea now that I think about it), and the edit was accepted by two users but then [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4093316) by the owner of the offensive post with the reason `there is no offense here. I am expressing my opinion`.

I then checked other answers by the user and noticed some of them had the same text in them (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jesus%20user:1081753)[link is now dead..nevermind, the posts were all unlocked.]). So I flagged two of the answers explaining why I had flagged them and stating that there were other answers and the user refused to have the posts edited.

So my question is, was that the right thing to do? (I'm a little nervous now that the user might downvote me, since he knows who was trying to edit his post.) So what should I do about users who put controversial/religious or other offensive text in their posts for no apparent reason? Thanks for helping me clear this up.

Note: I am a Christian (so the text could be viewed as good or bad or neutral to me), so it's not so much about the content of the post, but the irrelevance of it (and the refusal to remove it after a mod did).

Comment: Jesus Christ ...

Comment: Is it really offensive ? " thanks to Jesus Christ!"

Comment: I don't really consider it offensive, but the last thing you should do is start an editwar. Just flag the post again and stay out of it if the user rollbacks an edit made by a moderator.

Comment: Well, I mean, it could be (it bothered me a little). And it's completely unnecessary. But my question is more "what should I do with something like this (like if the text is much worse)" and "Did I handle this situation correctly?"

Comment: I agree that it's unnecessary in this context. not offensive, just looks funny

Comment: I would personally have removed it simply because it adds nothing and is noise.  I don't see how it could possibly be seen as offensive.

Comment: @Servy, that is most of the reason I removed it. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: There are three users called Jesus Christ I see.  Maybe he read an answer by one of them and was just giving attribution.

Comment: @McNab, he had that in more than one post.

Comment: @McNab, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jesus+user%3A1081753

Comment: @Habib - its noise

Comment: "thanks to Jesus Christ" ....that offensive text removed from answer..:P BTW i dont find that text offensive although i am agree with you .. that those are unnecessary .. i would rather think this is  like thanks, me too ,tag line  which should be removed

Comment: What about it? I think it is unnecessary if that's what you mean, would would probably just remove it (unless the user rollsback).

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4093741 But did you think the text was unnecessary then? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1316608/revisions thanks for removing that though

Comment: i have no idea why they rejected that edit ... anyways i have edited answer

Comment: If you get offended by "Jesus Christ" you should probably step away from those situations.

Comment: It wasn't so much I was offended, I just saw no need for the text.

Comment: He appears to accept his own answers to his questions more often than anyone; I understand this is acceptable, but the ratio is surely odd.

Comment: The idea of the Lord God whispering Ajax tips into this fellow's ear is extraordinarily humorous.

Comment: @RobertHarvey supplied an answer which addresses this situation here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222590/226446

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid Edit-Wars?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64085/how-to-avoid-edit-wars)

Comment: Ernest: you may laugh as long as you want. But God is who created all you see and all you cannot see, He is who made energy and mater, and He is the best doctor, physicist, and sure programmer.

Comment: davidsbro: the topic if the words are irrelevant or no - is very relative. From my point of view this is very relevant. Why is it relevant to mention about the source of the answer - like a book? This is just everyone's point of view and there is no offense about thanking God in providing answers.

Comment: @ihtus, you are almost trying to make it sound like you're receiving special revelation from God...which I don't think is likely (though not impossible). The reason you thanking God vs a book are different because people can validate the book; it's much harder to validate something God told you personally.

Comment: davidsbro: I am not saying I heard a voice from God saying this is the answer (though this can happen in other critical moments of life), what I am saying is God helped me finding the answer and I am thankful for this. That concrete answer is posted here and could be "validated" if you wish. And please remember, God does not love me more than you, and everyone can have His revelations, it depends on us, do we want this?

Comment: @ihtus, this all comes down to authority. SO doesn't want you thanking like that, and as a Christian you should obey them and post that were you're allowed to (like on your profile). I'm sorry, I would agree with you, but as long as my authority isn't making me do something **wrong**, I'm going to obey it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't get into an edit war.  If you feel that a post is inappropriate, edit it, and it is rolled back, the flag the post, and don't edit it again.  A moderator will be able to resolve the issue in ways that you simply cannot.

Given that the mod's edit was rolled back you should have simply flagged the post again, not edited it.  If they feel that it's warranted, they can lock the post after editing it to prevent future edits.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if moderators could lock an edit like that. I did flag it after the user rejected my edit.

Comment: @davidsbro It's also key to *stop editing the post*.  At that point you're just contributing to the problem, not the solution.  Back away.

Comment: after the second edit I realized I was just digging myself into a hole and so stopped. But you're right, next time I won't get as involved as I did this time.

Comment: @davidsbro [Looks like the OP of the answer is more than willing to continue the rollback war...](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8930512/revisions) :)

Comment: Yeah, wow. Do you know why it was unlocked?

Comment: @davidsbro I think it was only put on a timed locked that expired after an hour.

Comment: @Mysticial, So should the mods relock it? He appears to have put the text in more than one answer now... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jesus%20user:1081753

Comment: Just flag one of the posts and explain the situation. They'll do what they need to do.